# angular office fabric ui table, get selected items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, office-ui-fabric

I am working on an angular app that uses ngOfficeUiFabric for their components.

What I want to do is get the selected items from the existing table component.

http://ngofficeuifabric.com/demos/uifTable/

in the documentation is says this is available with the `table.selectedItems` property. The problem is that I need this outside of the hierarchy of the table. 
Is there a way for me to bind that table property to a variable in my controller?

I am new to both angular and office ui fabric so if I am missing something obvious please excuse me!

regards

Answer (score 1):

There is *table.selectedItems property*, you can get records form this property